# how much innodb_buffer_pool_size need to keep under my.ini file?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have Windows Werver 2012 R2 with installed physical memory 672GB. Can you please suggest `innodb_sort_buffer_size`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not discarding anything of @Rick James. But I want to add some more points for Original Poster (OP), regarding of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

The `innodb_buffer_pool_size` default value is `128MB`.

As MySQL docs says [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) the buffer pool size must always be equal to or a multiple of `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances`. If you configure `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a value that is not equal to, or a multiple of, `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances`, buffer pool size is automatically adjusted to a value that is equal to or a multiple of `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances` that is not less than the specified buffer pool size.

The maximum value of innodb_buffer_pool_size is 4294967295 (2^32-1) on 32-bit systems and 18446744073709551615 (2^64-1) on 64-bit systems. On 32-bit systems, the CPU architecture and operating system may impose a lower practical maximum size than the stated maximum. When the size of the buffer pool is greater than 1GB, setting `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` to a value greater than `1` can improve the scalability on a busy server.

For more information about buffer pool the blog of Morgan Tocker has clearly mentioned the **Default** & **Minimum value** of buffer pool [here](http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html).

Answer (score 0):

`innodb_sort_buffer_size` defaults to 1MB.  That is *probably* good enough.  However, since you have a huge amount of RAM, let's say 4MB might be a little bet better.

I assume you set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to somewhere around 500G -- Setting that is the most important thing for InnoDB.  (Exactly 500 is *not* important.).  And `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` should be 16?

The above recommendations assume that all (or most) of the use of the server will be for MySQL.  And it assumes you are using InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Comment: Thank you @Rick James yes its we are using INNODB table , can you please suggest me in simple terms how innodb_sort_buffer size helps in , did it help on performance or queries ?

Comment: @SAMAB - Simply put, the buffer_pool_size is the #1 tunable for performance of virtually all types of queries.  It controls the size of the "cache"; in turn, that controls how much I/O needs to be done.  I/O is the slowest part of any operation.  (672GB is an odd size, was that a typo?)